# An array pointer comparison error

Tags: c, arrays

*Its a simple insert and display elements in an array code that I have done.*

```
'    

#include<stdio.h>
int insert(int *arr);
int display(int *arr);
int main()
{

int MAX=5;
int arr[MAX];
insert(arr);
display(arr);
}
int insert(int *arr)
{
int n,i;
printf("Enter how many elements");
scanf("%d",&n);
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            printf("Enter value at arr[%d]\n",i);
            scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
        }
return *arr;
}


int display(int *arr)
{
        int i;
        printf("The values are::");
        for(i=0;arr[i]!=NULL;i++)//This loop is giving some trouble
        {
                printf("\n a[%d]->%d \n",i,arr[i]);
        }
        return *arr;
}

'
```

**Output**::
    **In function 'display':
    prog.c:33:24: error: comparison between pointer and integer
          for(i=0;arr[i]!=NULL;i++)
                        ^**
    This is the error am not able to solve.

Comment: I loose the enthusiasm to read the code when i see bad formatting. sigh.

Comment: I loose the enthusiasm to read the code when i see line numbers that mean nothing in an SO code block.

Comment: I am new to the site.Don't know much about the pattern in which code must be presented here.

Comment: Why do you think `integer array` will be `null terminated` ?

Comment: I actually wanted to put up a simple loop as for(i=0;i<n;i++) there. But since variable 'n' wuldnt be accessible there...I ended up with Null. Culd u pls help me using variable 'n' in the display function

Comment: @Oswarld  Calculate `n` in `main` and pass along in the function , Like this- `int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);`   . Pass `n` to functions with array and use it in loop .

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple things to be corrected in your code, but the error that you are getting is due to comparison between `pointer` (NULL) and an `int` `arr[i]`

```
for(i=0;arr[i]!=NULL;i++)
```

Your integer array `arr` does not have any `NULL` element in the end which can be compared. Perhaps you are confused between `string` and `integer arrays`.

Another thing that can be changed in your code, is the return type of your functions `insert()` and `delete()`. You are not recieveing the return values and thus its better to keep them void.

**A Suggestion**

Return `n` from the `insert()` function, receive it in `main()`. Then send it to the `display()` function along with the array, then use that in the `for` loop.

Best way to know the number of elements in an array that you are passing to a function is sending it to that function along with the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
'
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int MAX=5,i,pos,val;
int display(int *arr);
int main(void)
{
    int arr[MAX];
    display(arr);
}

int display(int *arr)
{
    printf("The values are::");
    for(i=0;i<MAX;i++)
    {
           printf("\n a[%d]-->%d ",i,arr[i]);
    }
        return *arr;
}'
```

*To avoid use of too many variables I continued the use of 'MAX' in the code.Making it global and it worked!!*